# RegEx for matching URLs and failing non-URLs

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract separated urls from srcset of an image.

This is for extracting and downloading all the files present in the row.
I am not hard coding it because row can differ from time to time.

```py
txt = "images/1x/1083bce6__color_272x92dp.png 1x, images/2x/b3716cd2_color_272x92dp.png 2x"

reg = re.compile(r"((?:[^\s,]+))(?:.*?,)?").finditer

for i in list(reg(txt)):
   print(i.group(1))
```

I expect the result to be two urls

```
images/1x/1083bce6__color_272x92dp.png
images/2x/b3716cd2_color_272x92dp.png
```

But I get three with extra being

`2x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we would add a quantifier to a simple char class in an expression such as:

```
[^\s]{4,}
```

to get our desired URLs.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfAfUY/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[^\s]{4,}"

test_str = "images/1x/1083bce6__color_272x92dp.png 1x, images/2x/b3716cd2_color_272x92dp.png 2x"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yfAfUY/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]